# Searching for an element in an array, and returning it

Tags: java, arrays, search, return

In a nutshell, this is my dilemma: 
I have imported a file that contains the top 2000 names in a given year in this format:

```
Mary, F, 2038 
Anna, F, 4230
```

(name, gender, how many people were named this in this particular year).

I have already created an array (type string) with this data. now, what I must do is allow the user to search for a name, and return their best year.
ex:
search for "sam"

output should be:

```
"isamar 1990"
"rosamond 1910"
"sam 1900"
"samantha 1990"
"samara 2000"
```

There is much more to the program than this, but I just need to know how to search within an array, return what I find in the array, and I'm done.

Comment: You should consider revising your data structure.  A single array of strings is going to make things difficult and slow.

Comment: if names are distinct there is one datastructure which outshines everything else.

Comment: If you managed to load a text file into the array (which is a nontrivial task), how come you don't know how to search in the array?

Comment: Bernard, I haven't tried much.  I really don't know how to search within an array.

Comment: Pilotcam, I know but it's slow to do it by strings but what the rubric says :/

Answer (score 5):

Searching an array can be as simple as iterating it and comparing each element to the desired terms.  For example, suppose you have the following model:

```
public class CommonName {
  public final String name;
  public final int year;
  public final CommonName(String name, int year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
  }
}
```

Assuming that you have already loaded the file as an array of these objects in `loadedNames` than you can search them using the [`String#indexOf(String)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) as such:

```
public static CommonName[] loadedNames = /* ... */;
public static Collection<CommonName> search(String searchTerm) {
  Collection<CommonName> matches = new ArrayList<CommonName>();
  for (CommonName cn : loadedNames) {
    if (cn.name.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0) { matches.add(cn); }
  }
  return matches;
}
```

Of course, there are other concerns such as case-sensitivity and performance (array searching is `O(n)`) which you might need to address.

Comment: i like your ans, using a map<String name, int year> would make it O(1) Time complexity?

Comment: Nope, you'd still have to search the whole map. Still O(N). Not sure if you can get around that for this problem.

Comment: See, I have to search multiple arrays, each array male and female names for a given year. Will this still work if I just copy and paste and do it for all of the arrays? (I have 262 arrays in total, so if there is a more efficient way please let me know)

Comment: why not merge them all into a single data structure or class like shown above? Can you give us the exact definition which the consumer needs for calling your program?

Comment: I do need that class, but I'm also required to have another class to handle the data getting loaded. In the second class, I need two instance ArrayLists for male and female for each year. I then must have an instance to read each file (131 total, for 131 years) in the main. He's not particular about the searching method, he said multiple if statements should be fine.  If I could upload the rubric I could, its too long to copy and paste... I'm sorry for the vauge-ness.  And thank you everyone for the help.